# Mock User.Identity in ASP.NET Core for Unit Testing

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-core-mvc, xunit

I am struggling to implement unit testing for action methods that incorporate `User.Identity.Name` functionality. The methods that I've come across fail because the properties that they suggest writing to throw 'read-only' errors (e.g. writing to `HttpContext` or the controller `User`)

I have an action method:

```
[Authorize]
        public async Task<ViewResult> EditProject(int projectId)
        {
            Project project = repository.Projects.FirstOrDefault(p => p.ProjectID == projectId);
            if (project != null)
            {
            //HOW DO I MOCK USER.IDENTITY.NAME FOR THIS PORTION?
                var user = await userManager.FindByNameAsync(User.Identity.Name); 
                bool owned = await checkIfUserOwnsItem(project.UserID, user);
                if (owned)
                {
                    return View(project);
                }
                else
                {
                    TempData["message"] = $"User is not authorized to view this item";
                }
             }
            return View("Index");
        }
```

If I want to unit test this action method, how can I mock up the `User.Identity` object?

```
[Fact]
        public async Task Can_Edit_Project()
        {
            //Arrange
            var user = new AppUser() { UserName = "JohnDoe", Id = "1" };
            Mock<IRepository> mockRepo = new Mock<IRepository>();
            mockRepo.Setup(m => m.Projects).Returns(new Project[]
            {
                new Project {ProjectID = 1, Name = "P1", UserID = "1"},
                new Project {ProjectID = 2, Name = "P2", UserID = "1"},
                new Project {ProjectID = 3, Name = "P3", UserID = "1"},
            });
            Mock<ITempDataDictionary> tempData = new Mock<ITempDataDictionary>();
            Mock<UserManager<AppUser>> userMgr = GetMockUserManager();
            //Arrange
            ProjectController controller = new ProjectController(mockRepo.Object, userMgr.Object)
            {
                TempData = tempData.Object,
            };


           //HOW WOULD I MOCK THE USER.IDENTITY.NAME HERE?
           //The example below causes two errors:
           // 1) 'Invalid setup on a non-virtual (overridable in VB) member
           //mock => mock.HttpContext
           //and 2) HttpContext does not contain a definition for IsAuthenticated
           var mock = new Mock<ControllerContext>();
           mock.SetupGet(p => p.HttpContext.User.Identity.Name).Returns(user.UserName);
          mock.SetupGet(p => p.HttpContext.Request.IsAuthenticated).Returns(true);

            //Act
            var viewResult = await controller.EditProject(2);
            Project result = viewResult.ViewData.Model as Project;

            //Assert
            Assert.Equal(2, result.ProjectID);
        }
```

EDIT:
Making some progress by adding the code below.

```
var claims = new List<Claim>()
            {
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, "John Doe"),
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, "1"),
                new Claim("name", "John Doe"),
            };
            var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, "TestAuthType");
            var claimsPrincipal = new ClaimsPrincipal(identity);

            var mockPrincipal = new Mock<IPrincipal>();
            mockPrincipal.Setup(x => x.Identity).Returns(identity);
            mockPrincipal.Setup(x => x.IsInRole(It.IsAny<string>())).Returns(true);

            var mockHttpContext = new Mock<HttpContext>();
            mockHttpContext.Setup(m => m.User).Returns(claimsPrincipal);
```

The `User.Identity.Name` is set properly now, but the line below still returns a `user = null`

`var user = await userManager.FindByNameAsync(User.Identity.Name);`

How can I make sure my mocked `UserManager` can return a mocked logged in user?

Comment: Just set it through ControllerContext

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To unit test my action method that uses

```
var user = await userManager.FindByNameAsync(User.Identity.Name);
```

I needed to:

1. set up my user

`var user = new AppUser() { UserName = "JohnDoe", Id = "1" };`

2. Set up my HttpContext to give data to return `user.UserName` in the `User.Identity.Name` object in the controller

```
var claims = new List<Claim>()
            {
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, user.UserName),
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, user.Id),
                new Claim("name", user.UserName),
            };
var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, "Test");
var claimsPrincipal = new ClaimsPrincipal(identity);

var mockPrincipal = new Mock<IPrincipal>();
mockPrincipal.Setup(x => x.Identity).Returns(identity);
mockPrincipal.Setup(x => x.IsInRole(It.IsAny<string>())).Returns(true);

var mockHttpContext = new Mock<HttpContext>();
mockHttpContext.Setup(m => m.User).Returns(claimsPrincipal);
```

3. Setup the mock `UserManager` to return the `user` object on the `FindByNameAsync` method

```
Mock<UserManager<AppUser>> userMgr = GetMockUserManager();
            userMgr.Setup(x => x.FindByNameAsync(It.IsAny<string>())).ReturnsAsync(user);
```

Edit:

```
public Mock<UserManager<AppUser>> GetMockUserManager()
{
    var userStoreMock = new Mock<IUserStore<AppUser>>();
    return new Mock<UserManager<AppUser>>(
        userStoreMock.Object, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null);
}
```

Comment: What is the : GetMockUserManager() ? I just can't access it, it doesn't exists

Comment: @ChristopheChenel It's a custom function to return a mocked `UserManager`. I'll add it to the answer.

Answer (score 20):

Set your fake `User` through `ControllerContext`

```
var context = new ControllerContext
{
    HttpContext = new DefaultHttpContext
    {
        User = fakeUser
    }
};

// Then set it to controller before executing test
controller.ControllerContext = context;
```

Comment: Do I have to use implicit conversion from `AppUser` to `ClaimsPrincipal` to get this to work? This gives me a 'method or operation not implemented' error

Comment: Where is fakeUser being set?

Comment: @AndrewGray `fakeUser` would be something like `new User(any special settings you want)`

Comment: To set fakeUser, see answer by Fancy5g and my comment there.

Answer (score 2):

You can create fakeContext and use that. See below:

```
var fakeContext = new Mock<HttpContextBase>();
var fakeIdentity = new GenericIdentity("User");
var principal = new GenericPrincipal(fakeIdentity, null);
fakeContext.Setup(x => x.User).Returns(principal);
var projectControllerContext = new Mock<ControllerContext>();
projectControllerContext.Setup(x => 
  x.HttpContext).Returns(fakeContext.Object);
```

Comment: Should this be working in Core? I get an error on `HttpContextBase` (namespace not found) and an error on `principal` 'cannot convert from GenericPrincipal to ?'

Comment: this wont work in asp net core.

Comment: You can piece together with other answers and make it work. At least the `var fakeIdentity = new GenericIdentity("tester");` part is helpful. Now you can add `var fakeUser = new ClaimsPrincipal(fakeIdentity);` and make the answer by Fabio work.